# Eureka вложенное поле

Tags: ios, swift, form

Добрый день 
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka
Необходимо сделать multiselect поле с двойной вложенностью, на примере с MultipleSelectorRow, который есть в Eureka
Например:
Есть поле "Марка автомобиля", кликаем на него, переходим на следующий уровень, где есть опции:

- Audi
- BMW
- Ford

Так вот, при клике на Audi, мне нужно чтобы элемент не выбирался, а переходил еще на один уровень, где пользователь уже может выбрать:

- A2
- A6
- A7